# beginning of my coding journey. Few hours in. How do I limit the input to integers in line 2 (from 1-1000)?

Tags: python-3.x

```
mortgage = 153000
credit_score = input ("What's your credit score? ") # here I want to limit the input to integers (1-1000).
if int(credit_score) >= 650:
    mortgage_payment = mortgage * 0.25
else:
    mortgage_payment= mortgage * 0.28
print (f'Your mortgage payment will be: ${mortgage_payment}')
```

Since it's just the beginning, I am still watching tutorials on how to code and learning along the way and try to make things more interesting + more complex. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
mortgage = 153000
credit_score = input ("What's your credit score? ") # here I want to limit the input to integers (1-1000).
if int(credit_score) >= 650 and credit_score in range(1,10001):
    mortgage_payment = mortgage * 0.25
else:
    mortgage_payment= mortgage * 0.28
print (f'Your mortgage payment will be: ${mortgage_payment}')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).